# Date in Dropdown list box

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have 3 drop down list having Date,Month ,Year.So when Updating I want this 3 Field to be a single Datafield in Sql Database. Iam using Asp.Net 2.0 Version(VB.Net).(Now these 3 Dropdown list values are saved as 3 Datafields in sql Database)

Answer (score 5):

Why not use a date/time picker instead?  It seems to me to be a better idea than your own triplet of day, month and year.

Comment: This reduces the chance of honest mistakes.  With a good calendar control, an honest user isn't going to enter "9/31/1977" or "2/29/1900".  (I know that you can repopulate the day list in javascript to correspond to the correct # of days in the month.)

Comment: This also reduces a lot of code for checking valid dates and updating the other controls based on a user selection from another.

Answer (score 2):

I take it you're using a SqlCommand for this?   Here's some sample, non-compiling code which I'll whip up for you here:

```
Dim cmd as SqlCommand("update tableX set dt = @var where ID = 1");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@var", new DateTime(CInt(day.SelectedValue), CInt(month.SelectedValue, CInt(year.SelectedValue)));

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: It blows and exception in the DateTime Constructor so you wont get bad dates in the DB but the user experience ain't going to be good.

Comment: If the DateTime constructor throws, you could always, uh, catch it.

Answer (score 0):

Join up the values:

month + "/" + day + "/" + year

and use DateTime.Parse() or DateTime.TryParse() to convert them to a date. If you are concerned about the date format for your culture, pass in a CultureInfo object. Add your own validation as needed.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx

Not foolproof, but it might satisfy your requirement.